# Calculate the height of a row in this scheduler calendar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, counting

I am looking for an SQL solution to pass onto my HTML javascript to alter the height of a row.

**SCENARIO**

I want to count the number of "rows" that will determine, how high (CSS height) this row should be to accommodate all the possible number of bars in this calendar.

For example, here we have 5 vessels in my calendar from the 5th Feb 2023, up to the 8th Feb 2023.

[image]

And here is the row data I want to "count" to give me '3' not '5'.

[image]

How do I count these records to find what's overlapped so I get the result of '3'? This I will use in javascript to adjust the height of my row to allow the number of bars to fit inside it.

Thanks

Comment: Feels like you are looking for a Gaps and Islands.   First 3 rows would have a count of 3 and last two would have a count of 2.     Sample data as text would be more helpful.

Comment: What is the exception criteria for not counting the record? You won't be able to code it until you can put it in English sentence!

Comment: @PriyankPanchal - humph. I thought my English was simple enough ;)

Comment: The exception is the two rows on the right. As you can see they are on separate date range, so overall I want my SQL to return 3 rows which will accomodate the 2 rows on the right by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking of maximum number of overlapping dates. You can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the 2 dates and then perform a cumulative sum of the value (1 as Arrival, -1 as Departure). Finally `MAX()` will gives you the value that you want

```
select  max(c)
from
(
    select  c = sum(e) over (order by dt)
    from    vessels
            cross apply
            (
                values
                (Arrival,    1), -- arrival
                (Departure, -1)  -- departure
            ) e (dt, e)
) t
```

Comment: Nice approach !  +1

Comment: Thank you again. This worked, but could you please explain the e (dt, e) ? I've not seen this in SQL before. Thanks

Comment: `e` is the alias name given to the result of the value constructor and `dt` and `e` are simply the column alias for the name of the 2 columns from the value constructor